# Tinkerpop3/Gremlin. Find (A) Upsert (B) add Edge A to B

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am looking for an upsert functionality in Gremlin.

Client program has a stream of `(personId, favoriteMovieNodeId)` that need to query for the favoriteMovieNodeId's, then UPSERT a person Vertex and create the [favoriteMovie] edge.

this will create duplicate Person nodes:

```
g.V().has(label,'movies').has('uid',$favoriteMovieNodeId).as('fm')
.addV('Person').property('personId', $personId).addE('favMovie').to('fm')
```

Is there a way to check for existence of node based on properties before adding a node? I can't seem to find the documentation on this very basic graph function thats a part of every underlying graph db.

Answer (score 2):

If the movie is guaranteed to exist, then it's:

```
g.V().has('movies','uid',$favoriteMovieNodeId).as('fm').
  coalesce(V().has('Person','personId', $personId),
           addV('Person').property('personId', $personId)).
  addE('favMovie').to('fm')
```